# find a match with an element in my class c#

Tags: c#

I have the following JSON string

```
{  "Params": [ { "name": "id","value": "1234567" },
               { "name": "class","value": "six"}
             ],
   "type":"general"}
```

and equivalent class as below

```
public  class class1
{
    public Param[] Params { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Param
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I search if there is an object with name as id in Params array and how to fetch its value?

Comment: Just use LINQ maybe? `class1Value.Params.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "SomeName")?.Value` I don't see what it has to do with JSON or ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

Include `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then deserialize your json string to an object of `class1`, then search using linq.

```
string json = "{\"Params\": [ { \"name\": \"id\",\"value\": \"1234567\" },{ \"name\": \"class\",\"value\": \"six\"}],\"type\":\"general\"}";

// convert to object
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<class1>(json);

// filter
var result = jsonObject.Params.Where(p=> p.Name == "id" && p.Value == "1234567");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Json.net documentation has a pretty good example you can use as well. It shows a way to do without necessarily converting to a C# object. See below

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm